# how to save the output to the particular path in sparkR

Tags: r, hadoop, sparkr

I am running pi.R example using spark-submit.The output is displayed on the terminal but i want to save the output to the hdfs path.

```
/SparkR-pkg/lib/SparkR/sparkR-submit --master yarn-client examples/pi.R yarn-client 4
```

the above command is used to run the pi.r example

here is the pi.R code

```
library(SparkR)
args <- commandArgs(trailing = TRUE)
if (length(args) < 1) {
print("Usage: pi <master> [<slices>]")
q("no")
}
sc <- sparkR.init(args[[1]], "PiR")
slices <- ifelse(length(args) > 1, as.integer(args[[2]]), 2)
n <- 100000 * slices
piFunc <- function(elem) {
rands <- runif(n = 2, min = -1, max = 1)
val <- ifelse((rands[1]^2 + rands[2]^2) < 1, 1.0, 0.0)
val
}
piFuncVec <- function(elems) {
message(length(elems))
rands1 <- runif(n = length(elems), min = -1, max = 1)
rands2 <- runif(n = length(elems), min = -1, max = 1)
val <- ifelse((rands1^2 + rands2^2) < 1, 1.0, 0.0)
sum(val)
}
rdd <- parallelize(sc, 1:n, slices)
count <- reduce(lapplyPartition(rdd, piFuncVec), sum)
cat("Pi is roughly", 4.0 * count / n, "\n")
cat("Num elements in RDD ", count(rdd), "\n")
```

i want to save the above output in hdfs location.any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this on a cluster, but my guess is that regular R code will work here:

```
output <- paste("Pi is roughly", 4.0 * count / n, "\n")
output <- paste(output, "Num elements in RDD ", count(rdd), "\n")
write(output,file="pathToFile") #can be location.any
```

Comment: when i run the above code i got this error.Error in ifelse(append, "a", "w") : object 'w' not found
Calls: write -> cat -> file -> ifelse

Comment: Does it help when you use write(output,file="pathToFile", append=TRUE)?

Comment: even if i set the append as true i am getting same error,In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'hdfs://ip-172-31-41-199.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/user/karun/output/test1.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: Does file.exists('hdfs://ip-172-31-41-199.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/user/karun/output') returns TRUE or FALSE?